# Raspberry Pi3 + Raspbian - Serial connection to cp210x device driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, pyserial

I need some advice about this problem: I'm connecting my cp 210x device to my raspberry Pi3 with raspbian, thorugh USB-serial, but when i try dmesg, i get:

> "[ 282.796114] cp210x 1-1.4:1.0: cp210x converter detected
>
> [ 282.796396] cp210x 1-1.4:1.0: failed to get vendor val 0x370b size 1: -32
>
> [ 282.796407] cp210x 1-1.4:1.0: querying part number failed"

Generic code example:

```
import serial
with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600,timeout=1) as ser:
    ser.write(b'&00R')
    ser.write(b'&15R')
    x = ser.read()
    s = ser.read(10)
    line = ser.readline()
    print (line)
```

> print (line) = b''

If i try lsmod, I can see my "1 cp210x" there

If i try lsusb, I can see my "Bus 001 Device 007: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light" there

If I try uname -r, I get 4.19.25-v7+

If I try stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a, I can see that my baud is 9600

If I try lsb_release -r, I get 9.6

I know that my device is working because i can connect it through the same USB-serial to my computer with window and use it in another software, but I do need to use it now with my Raspberry+Raspbian+Python.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: That dmesg report could very well be harmless, and your code doesn't seem like it is actually failing, given that you do three reads and only display the last one.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried to print all of them, but without success, just forgot to put here the other "prints". With the command "&00R", my device should give back a lot of parameters.. but i'm receiving only b'' (nothing).
Thank you for trying to help jason!

Comment: Are you sure that the device doesn't need a carriage return and/or linefeed after that command?

Comment: I think yes, as i can just plug the usb of my device in my computer with Windows os, and using a normal software to read/write in the serial (doing the same connection), I can just say &00R and I start getting information.(And yes, I had to install the same driver on Windows).

Comment: https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers 
This driver, but it was already installed on Raspbian.

Comment: When you successfully use the device from Windows, are you connecting at 9600 baud as well?  Assuming that the "mySmartUSB light" description from lsusb is accurate, that appears to be a 115200 baud device...

Comment: No, I use 115200 on windows as you said. I tried to use  115200 on raspberry but I got only b'' (the same as with 9600).
Maybe I have to change the baud of the USB? Because when i try ("-F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a") I get baud as 9600. 
I don't know if it's possible to change the baud to 115200 (inside raspberry, not in the script) and then I would try with 115200 again.
Tomorrow I will try it again, I don't have the device here with me now to test.
Thank you for helping me jason!

Comment: So, today I tried a lot of things, but without success.
I tried changing the port baudrate to 115200, using the same 115200 in my script.
Still getting b''.
So i went to windows and tried to use some "Serial monitor softwares".  For example, using the "Free serial analyzer", using 115200 and connecting to the port, when i wrote "&00R" it gave me all values that i need to get. But when i tried this one, https://sourceforge.net/projects/readwriteserial/ and some others, I got nothing.

And I still with the problem [ 282.796396] cp210x 1-1.4:1.0: failed to get vendor val 0x370b size 1: -32.

Comment: @jasonharper as you said, the problem wasn't the driver...
The problem was that the guy that programmed the device that i was trying to get the values, forgot to tell me that, with the &00R, I should put CR together, so when I tried to send ser.write('&00R\r') it worked. Thank you for your time!